# How to implement role-based Authorization for Python REST API?

Tags: rest, python-3.x, authorization, restful-architecture, role-base-authorization

The basic architecture of my application is React front-end consuming a RESTful API sitting on top of a polyglot storage layer.

**Front-end:**
React consuming APIs

**Back-end:**
Python
Flask

***Authentication***
Auth0+OKTA

Everything is working great. However, I need to have different roles for the users. In other words, I need to control the actions that a user can perform on a resource based on the role.

**Example:**
*-User A wants to add a new user*
*-He has a token in his request, so I know User A is Authenticated*
*-Now I need to make sure he can in fact add users base on his role.*

I don't want to hard-code the user roles as suggested in other solutions, and I would like to allow for custom roles to be added.

Also, I want to be respectful of people's time, so if there is a resource that addresses my concern, please feel free to point me to it.

**These are my questions:**
 1. Are there any best practices for implementing what I am trying to accomplish?
 2. Could you point me to examples or tutorials discussing authorization(not authentication)?
 3. Do I check at each service call if the authenticated user can also perform the action or do I provide the roles in some form after authorization, so a service request contains both the authentication and authorization token?(this seems pretty easy to hack so I am guessing no...)

If I sound confused on the topic of authorization, it is because I am. Please feel free to point me to any resource that have been helpful to you.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a framework like [Yosai](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yosai) that is based on [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/).

These are some [features](https://github.com/YosaiProject/yosai):

- Enables Role-Based Access Control policies through permission-level and role-level access control
- Two-Factor Authentication, featuring Time-based One-Time Passwords
- Native Support for Caching and Serialization
- Event-driven Processing
- Ready for Web Integration